# Socket.EndReceive of IAsyncResult is collecting more TCP messages than one

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

I have a situation here.
I'm using System.Net.Sockets.Socket to read and send TCP messages.
Using the recursion for receiving the data and reading again new data.

```
void rcvTCP(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            var bytesRead = socket.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                var data = new byte[bytesRead];
                Array.Copy(this.mBuffer, data, data.Length);
                dataReceived(this, mMaster.SlaveAddress, data);
            }
            socket.BeginReceive(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(rcvTCP), socket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I'm sending messages from a device to my app, each 10ms, 8 bytes each message. I'm receiving the messages ok, so the "bytesRead" is 8, until a certain point when the app freezes randomly, and "bytesRead" is 768. When I look inside the data that came, I see that I have 96 messages in one.

I've read in the internet, like the messages are coming Sync instead of Async, so checking the "CompletedSinchronously" gives true at previous messages and this message also...

```
if (ar.CompletedSynchronously)
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

I tried with TcpClient + NetworkStream instead of Socket(I know that TcpClient is pretty the same as Socket), and I have the same result.
Please help me. **I want all the messages separated instead of collected**, but I can't find any solution to this...
Any idea how to do this?

PS: I am already putting the flag - NoDelay to true.

FIX: For me the fix was splitting the collected messages after the receive, and running the splitting in a separate thread, so the UI does not freeze. Keep in mind, if you have a property used in different Threads, don't forget to use "lock".

Comment: Yup, that's how TCP works! Get used to it because you can't change it. They are separated by the fact that you KNOW each message is 8 bytes. So 768 bytes means 96 messages. Beware, you could get 765 bytes and then 3 in the next one...

Comment: There is a problem. I'm still displaying this data on a graph, so it's time based. And imagine now the app is freezing for 1 second, and it gets 96 messages at ones. I can't display them on the graph. And the fact that it's freezing, that's annoying...

Comment: why can't you display them on the graph?

Comment: We will have different data in one point of time...

Comment: except not, because you know the sender is sending a certain number of messages per second... right?

Comment: Hmm... You are right... Just wondering. If I use UDP protocol instead, even if I loose data sometimes, will that get each message separate, or still something will be collected?

Comment: or you could evenly space them between the last measurement and the current time

Comment: Using UDP protocol, would work with each message separately, or it will still collect some messages in one? (not sure how UDP is working...)

Comment: Using UDP wouldn't solve any problem. The message isn't delayed because of the network. The message is delayed because your app froze. You still don't get any messages while the app is frozen because it's frozen. The messages would still get delayed until the app stopped freezing. So what would be the point?

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Even if the app would not freeze, I will have a gap for one second in the graph, that I will need to fill one second later based on the data that came collected, so to unfreeze would also not fix the problem